# Christoffel symbols in polar coordinates calculation

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, polar-coordinates

I'm currently studying Riemannian Geometry and I would like to get familiar with the basic concepts.

I considered the simple Riemannian manifold $(\mathbb{R}^2, can)$ with its Levi-Civita connection $\nabla$. 
I know that the Christoffel symbols are all $0$ according to the trivial coordinate system but I want to calculate what happen with the polar coordinates.

I want to calculate 
$$\Gamma_{\rho \rho}^\rho, \quad \Gamma_{\rho \rho}^\theta, \quad \Gamma_{\rho \theta}^\rho, \quad \Gamma_{\rho \theta}^\theta, \quad \Gamma_{\theta \theta}^\rho , \quad \Gamma_{\theta \theta}^\theta.
$$
(I don't need to calculate $\Gamma_{\theta \rho}^\rho$ and $\Gamma_{\theta \rho}^\theta$ because of the symmetry of the Levi-Civita connection.

Let's start for example with  $\Gamma_{\rho \rho}^\rho$. 
$$
\Gamma_{\rho \rho}^\rho = d\rho(\nabla_{\partial_\rho}\rho).
$$
**My idea** is to write $\partial_\rho $ with respect to the standard basis $\{\partial_1, \partial_2\}$ and to write $d\rho$ with respect to $\{dx_1, dx_2\}$ and use the properties of $\nabla$.

Therefore:
\begin{align}
\Gamma_{\rho \rho}^\rho &= d\rho(\nabla_{\partial_\rho}\rho) \\
&=(\cos\theta dx_1 + \sin\theta dx_2)\big(\nabla_{\cos\theta\partial_1 + \sin\theta\partial_2}\cos\theta\partial_1 + \sin\theta\partial_2\big)\\
&\quad\vdots \quad \text{(after some calculations)}\\
&=0.
\end{align}

I don't know if the result is correct. I would like to know if this is a correct way to solve the exercise. Are there any other strategies?

Thanks!

Comment: You are right! There was a mistake in my calculations. But still I would like to know if this was the best way to solve the exercise..

Comment: why not just deriving the (induced) polar metric? I mean that is the reason why u use levi-cevita connections right?

Comment: Ah, yeah, true! But is still OK my idea? Are there also other "elementary" ways?

Comment: When all you need is a quick verification that you computed the coefficients correctly so you google it but then you land upon a website that asks you if you've googled it. ¯\\_(ツ)\_/¯

Comment: For anyone else wondering, [see here](https://drchristiansalas.com/2017/03/11/geometric-interpretation-of-christoffel-symbols-and-some-alternative-approaches-to-calculating-them/). The symbols are somewhere down there if you scroll far enough. ;)